# Error Using Temporary Tables With Same Names SQL Server

Tags: sql, temp-tables

Here is my scenario. (Following is my stored proc taking @date as an input parameter)

```
DECLARE @date DATE

If object_id('tempdb..#TempList') is not null drop table #TempList
go

Create table #TempList (MILL_NO VARCHAR(7), SHIP_DATE DATE, BL_STATUS NCHAR(1), 
FOOTAGE DECIMAL(12,4))

If @date IS NULL

Insert into #TempList
Select mill_no, null, bl_status,footage from fn_A(0,0)

Select * from #TempList


If object_id('tempdb..#TempList') is not null drop table #TempList
go

Create Table #TempList (MILL_NO VARCHAR(7), SHIP_DATE DATE, BL_STATUS NCHAR(1),
FOOTAGE DECIMAL(12,4))

If @date IS NOT NULL

Insert into #TempList
Select * from fn_B(0,'06/06/2006')

Select * from #TempList
```

I figured out from one of the posts that I cannot use temporary tables with same names unless I inclide a GO. However, including GO is not taking the parameters I try to pass.

Is there an alternate approach to eliminate this error?

Comment: Why drop and recreate the temporary table?  Why not just truncate it?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the procedure supplied, you could use `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead.

I don't see a point dropping and recreating a table if all you want to do is quickly remove the records.

**EDIT**

You don't drop and recreate your table with the same name; instead of this code:

```
If object_id('tempdb..#TempList') is not null drop table #TempList go  
Create Table #TempList (
    MILL_NO VARCHAR(7), 
    SHIP_DATE DATE, 
    BL_STATUS NCHAR(1), 
    FOOTAGE DECIMAL(12,4)
)
```

Just do this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #TempList
```

Comment: How can I have a temporary table with same name if not drop it ?

Comment: Though I appreciate the fact that truncate deletes data in my #table, I don't understand the concept of it to resolve my issue here. My situation here is to insert data into the temporary tables(having same name) from **two different functions (fn_A, fn_B).** And I am unable to do that because I need to check if @date is null or not before inserting.

Comment: Why do the temporary tables *have* to have the same name?

Comment: Because the temp table needs to be called further down in the stored proc. Some additional functionality is to be applied on it. And creating two temporary tables will unnecessarily make my functionality redundant and complex.

Answer (score 0):

`if object_id('tempdb..#TempList')`  is allways NULL because `#TempList` is not the name that results created on tempdb's sysobjects table when you do `create table #TempList`

**EDIT**
what about this:

```
CREATE PROC PIRULO(@date as DATE) as

Create table #TempList (MILL_NO VARCHAR(7), SHIP_DATE DATE, BL_STATUS NCHAR(1), FOOTAGE DECIMAL(12,4))
IF @date IS NULL
    Insert into #TempList
    Select mill_no, null, bl_status,footage from fn_A(0,0)
ELSE
    Insert into #TempList
    Select * from fn_B(0,'2006/06/06')    -- also I changed date order.

Select * from #TempList
```

Comment: then why does SQL say 'There is already an object named '#TempList' in the database.'?

Comment: The second part of this answer is correct but the first part isn't. `OBJECT_ID` works as the OP is using it.

Comment: SQL say 'There is already an object named '#TempList' because the `drop table #TempList` was not executed, because `object_id('tempdb..#TempList')` was null, because `tempdb..#TempList` is not the way to reference that table

Comment: @LuisSiquot - You are wrong. Test it. `Create table #TempList (x INT); SELECT object_id('tempdb..#TempList')`

Comment: I must belive you, i have no access to mssql now

Answer (score 0):

I struggled all these days to insert values into same temporary table when a given condition is met.

Given that I am on a project migrating FoxPro(which has cursors declared all over) to SQL Server this small logic needed to be implemented in multiple stored procs.

Finally, what I learned out of this is - Think Straight Before Trying Anything Different (suggestion to my co-beginners in DB migration).

```
DECLARE @date DATE

SET @date = '06/06/2006'    --@date = null

If object_id('tempdb..#TempList') is not null drop table #TempList

Create table #TempList (MILL_NO VARCHAR(7), SHIP_DATE DATE, BL_STATUS NCHAR(1), 
FOOTAGE DECIMAL(12,4))

If @date = null

-- Here I am inserting null in place of Ship_Date because fn_A returns only 3 columns in my case
Insert into #TempList
Select mill_no, null, bl_status,footage from fn_A(0,0)

--Select * from #TempList

else

Insert into #TempList
Select * from fn_B(0,@date)

Select * from #TempList
```

Thanks everyone for giving your inputs. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: isn't your code exactly what I had suggested??  in fact the only diference is the check of the existence of #TempList table.  but, be sure it is redundant as temp tables has store procedure scope

Comment: i did think about your answer when i got my own(like syntactically what you suggested is same).. but you suggested truncating the data and my requirement was to reuse #table with same name..

Comment: that is the other anwser, I have't mention TRUNCATE. you can at least mark as a good anwser, as you can mark many anwsers as "good answer"

Comment: my apologies.. i mistook you to littlebobbytables.. coming to your answer  you suggested object_id('tempdb..#TempList') is always null.. if thats the case my code will not execute more than once.. Also, do not get me wrong, **I DID NOT** down mark your answer.. I never do that.. But Thank you for your input.. I am doing 'answer useful' now.. Your answer did help me learn something new..